# Cannot install Linux

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have a new desktop pc with a 1TB m.2 disk and two 480GB ssd disks. I have installed Windows 11 in the m.2 disk and now I want to install Linux Fedora 36 on a ssd disk.
The problem is that at a certain point of the setup (installing software, or bootloader or configuring storage), the process freezes.
I have tried also with Fedora 35 and Linux Mint, with same result.
Same result installing Fedora on m.2 disk.
Iso were generated both with Rufus and Fedora Media Writter.
Where is the problem? First time I encounter this issue.
Thanks.

UPDATE: images from the Linux Fedora 36 console during installation; is there anything interesting?
[image]

[image]

UPDATE #2: here the  [system-info script result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mDO4-YQIHmxy78a7rYUhpqrnYD4b_pz1/view?usp=sharing); I ran it from the live Fedora 36 version.

Comment: Can you access the installer logs on other virtual consoles (Ctrl+Alt+function keys)? What processor and chipset is in the desktop?

Comment: If you are open to try also [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/), I suggest that you try the Ubuntu Forum's [**system-info script**](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/) and let it upload the result to a pastebin. The first choice would be Ubuntu Desktop. If there are problems with graphics, you might try with Ubuntu Server or even [extract this *amd64* compressed image file](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current/) to the USB drive and run the system-info script from there. These details about the computer will help us help you.

Comment: @telcoM I'm on an AMD Ryzen 5 5600g (integrated graphic)

Comment: Is the drive configured as some kind of RAID? In that case select AHCI. You can enable the AHCI mode in BIOS settings before the installation. (This might spoil Windows, which would need to be reinstalled, if on the same disk, but should be no problem if Windows and Linux are on different disks).

Comment: @sudodus no raid here; there is an m.2 1TB drive with Windows 11 (GPT) and other two 480GB (GPT) disks.

Comment: @user1, Without more information we can only guess. Please consider running the system-info script (from a live system in a USB drive).

Comment: @sudodus I have inserted the link to the system-info script result.

Comment: Try resetting BIOS settings. If it doesn't help, I've no idea. This looks mighty weird. Running Memtest86 for an hour would be nice: https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm This looks like a HW issue.

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov: the bios has already been reset with default values; I have also updated the bios to the last version. The mistery is that Windows has no problem. It's incredible...

Comment: Is the TUF GAMING B550M-E motherboard very new? In that case it is possible, that some linux driver is missing? Is Fedora running well (live from USB)? I mean for example graphics and network. -- Thanks for uploading results from the system-info script :-) But several pieces of information are missing, because the script is made to work with Ubuntu. Anyway, if you can make [this amd64 compressed image file](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/jammy/daily-preinstalled/current/) work from USB, you should also be able to clone it from the image file to an internal drive and test it.

Comment: If it works (as a server in text mode), you can install some desktop environment and make that work later on. See also [this link to my thread at the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692). It might also work better to try the Kinetic Kudu compressed image file, which has a newer linux kernel than 22.04.

Comment: @sudodus the mobo is new; Fedora running well from live USB (both graphic and network). Should I use MRB for both Windows and Linux (currently I'm using GPT for both). Should I replace the 5600g with a "normal" CPU and a graphic card? Or is a mobo issue? I assembled my new matx pc yesterday (not the first time I do it);  I don't know what to do at this point!

Comment: If you clone from a compressed image file, it will also create the partition table. Otherwise, if you install Linux with an installer, I suggest that you use the modern GPT. I think it is too early to start swapping hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I tried also with a pci graphic card with no result.
Installed the fedora server with success, install the Cinnamon Desktop Environment; errors while starting the desktop.
No, this is not the expected behavior from a Linux distribution; I suspect a defect in the cpu and / or in the motherboard.
I will ask for a replacement.